# cant update row mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Okay so i'm trying to create an available column to increment once the same fields are entered, but it doesn't seem to work and i've been trying for ages. I know the codes a mess but please can someone help?

```
  $make = strtolower($_POST['make']);
  $fuel = $_POST['fuel'];
  $transmission = $_POST['transmission'];
  $size = $_POST['size'];
  $doors = $_POST['doors'];
  /*$date = time();*/

  date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
  $date = date('y-m-d');

  $connect = mysql_connect ("localhost", "root", "**********");
  mysql_select_db ("car");

  $query = "SELECT * FROM type WHERE make = '$make'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  $row = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $amount = $row+1;
  $id = $make."[".$amount."]";

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

      if ($make&&$fuel&&$transmission&&$size&&$doors)
      {
          /*if ($fuel!== $fueltype['0','1','2','3'])*/
          if ($fuel=='text')
          {
                $msg = ("Please enter a valid fuel type: Petrol, Diesel, LPG or Electric");
          }
          else
          if ($transmission=='text')
          {
              $msg = ('Please enter a valid transmission type: Manual, Auto or Semi-auto');

          }
          else
          if(strpos($size,".") == false){
             $msg = ('Please enter the valid engine size: 1.0, 1.4, 1.6 etc');
          }
          else
          if(!preg_match("/^[0-9]+$/",$doors)){
            $msg = ('Please enter the number of doors. 3, 5 etc');
          }
          else{
          //Creates the id
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM type");
      $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

      if ($numrows!=0){

          while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
            $dbid = $row["id"];
            $dbmake = $row["make"];
            $dbfuel = $row["fuel"];
            $dbtransmission = $row["transmission"];
            $dbsize = $row["size"];
            $dbdoors = $row["doors"];
          }

          if  ($make==$dbmake&&$fuel==$dbfuel&&$transmission==$dbtransmission&&$size==$dbsize&&$doors==$dbdoors){

            print_r($dbid);
            print_r($dbmake);
            print_r($dbfuel);
            print_r($dbtransmission);
            print_r($dbsize);
            print_r($dbdoors);
                    mysql_query("UPDATE type SET available=available+1 ON DUPLICATE KEY id = id ");
          }
          else{

            //increments the available column '$make'+'[#]'
          $query = "SELECT * FROM type WHERE id = '$id'";
          $result = mysql_query($query);
          $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
          $inc = $numrows+1;
          $available = $inc;


          $query = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO type VALUES ('$id', '$make', '$fuel', '$transmission', '$size', '$doors', '$date', '$available')");
          $msg = ("Car has been added to database. <a href='database.php'>View database?</a>");
          }
          }
          }
          }
```

Comment: You need to narrow down your question. It's not a good idea to paste your whole script and say "here, fix this".

Comment: **WARNING!** Your code suffers from an [SQL injection vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  Please use a *non-deprecated* database interface, like [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) so you can leverage [parameterized queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement).

Comment: You have sql injection vulnerabilities. You shouldn't use the mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and it's probably not a great idea to post your database password in a public forum

Comment: This is what an `auto_increment` field in MySQL is for.

Comment: It would be EXTREMELY helpful if you posted what is currently happening.  Where is the error happening?  what are the variable values?  do some print statements.

Comment: but i need it to increment once the same data is updated in that selected row. using auto_increment wouldn't be useful here?

Comment: mysql_query("UPDATE type SET available=available+1 ON DUPLICATE KEY id = id ");

Answer (score 2):

This is not addressing your question, because there's way too much going on in your code to pinpoint where your issue lies.

However, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. If you plan on uploading this to some sort of website that people may use, please please either use PHP PDO parameterization or otherwise sanitize all of your input.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing the SQL statement to:

```
"UPDATE type SET available=available+1 where id='$dbid'"
```

I am not sure about the ON Duplicate used in the query and if it is valid, you are using id=id